# SharePoint InfoPath List Dropdown Lookup

Tags: infopath, custom-list, lookup-column, dropdown

There is a problem that I am experiencing with a InfoPath form I am creating.

I have two SharePoint Lists. 
1 - Contains the database of assets
2 - Will contain the test logs for each of the assets in List 1

I have designed the InfoPath form in List 2 to look up data from List 1.
It is a simple rule based lookup on the serial number of the asset in List 1.

When I get the results back in List 2 the fields in List 1 which are Dropdown boxes are looked up but comes back as the ID number not the name.

Does anyone know why this is happening? If you need more info please just ask. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to List Settings -> click on your Lookup Field -> check if this setting is set to Title:

[image]

Comment: Yep that's all set correctly. In List 1 you can select the name from the dropdown but when List 2 is referencing the dropdown in List 1 it appears as a number.